# Does pure opengl depend on the cpu speed?

Tags: opengl

Does a pure opengl animation (such as the one in cinebench) depend only on the gpu? Im asking this because I ran the benchmark on a gt610 and I only get 9 fps on a pentium 4. However the same card with a better cpu gets 16 fps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does matter. Depending on the application it varies greatly though. At worst the CPU has to be able to keep up with the load on the GPU and help move data around. Something is always going to be a bottleneck for heavy operations. That's why when I build or buy a PC I never spend a significant portion on one component. Disk, RAM, CPU, and GPU must all be comparable to get the best rounded performance. Unless you are only using one application all the time that takes very heavy advantage of one component. Otherwise, DirectX, OpenGL, and OpenCL will all take the best advantage when the GPU is paired with a good CPU too.